# Combine items from two listboxes into a third listbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to combine the contents of two listboxes such that if ListBox 1 has A,B,C in it and ListBox 2 has 1,2,3 in it, the output in ListBox 3 would be: A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3. My code below almost does that, but it writes over the A and B iterations and only shows the C iteration. What am I missing here?

string A;
string B;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        A =  listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        B = listBox2.Items[j].ToString();
        listBox3.Items.Add(A + ": " + B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `A` & `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        A =  listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
        for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            B = listBox2.Items[j].ToString();
            listBox3.Items.Add(A + ": " + B);
        }
    }
}
```

I moved the second for loop into the first one. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're missing the fact, that first loop is over when second one starts. And that's why `A` is always the last value from first listbox. Nest the loops instead:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        A =  listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

        for (int j = 0; j < listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            B = listBox2.Items[j].ToString();

            listBox3.Items.Add(A + ": " + B);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use LINQ then this works nicely:

```
        var items =
            from A in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
            from B in listBox2.Items.Cast<string>()
            select A + ": " + B;

        listBox3.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Comment: Most C#-esque solution (and best), imo.

Comment: @Tetramputechture - I think so too. I personally like it because I can quickly glance at it and tell that it is correct. The `for`-loop methods are much harder to do that with.